# CMU PocketSphinx Recognize a dynamically entered word

Tags: android, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx-android

Is there a method in pocketSphinx library, which would allow me to take input a word [name,nickname] as text from the user and then it can recognize it when that word is said.

The flow would be - user inputs the word, then start the recognizer and when he says the word it is recognized. The word would not be common English word, rather would be a name or nickname.

Other option for me is gather all possible words in my region possible and make grammar for them, but obviously I would love a better solution. Pocket sphinx is used because continuous listening is required. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add and delete keyword search any time, something like this:

```
private static final String SEARCH_NAME = "kws";

/* Word you want to check */
public void recognizeWord(String word ) {
       recognizer.setKeyphrase(SEARCH_NAME, word);
       recognizer.setSearch(SEARCH_NAME);
       recognizer.startListening(SEARCH_NAME);
}
```